# Using /tellraw with certain scoreboard conditions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to do something on a server. I have a scoreboard set up called "WD" and I want a `/tellraw` command to talk to people who's "WD" score equals 1.

I have tried doing:

```
/tellraw @a[score_WD=1] {"text":"Click this!","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/say Hello!"}}
```

But this does nothing. How do I do this? The default score of "WD" is 0. I am using 1.7.10.

Comment: Try `@a[score_WD=1,score_WD_min=1]` Does that help?

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@a[score_WD=1,score_WD_min=1]
```

This means the *maximum* score they can have is `1`, and the *minimum* score they can have is `1`. So, the only score they can have is `1`.

---

You command becomes

```
/tellraw @a[score_WD=1,score_WD_min=1] {"text":"Click this!","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/say Hello!"}}
```